# copy table data from one db to another with where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two database with same number of tables & table structure.
I want to copy data from  one table into another with where condition.

I have tried this below query, Is the below query is correct,

```
 INSERT INTO db2.table (SELECT * FROM db1.table t  where t.restaurant_id=12);
```

Please help

**update**: i am looking for a single query similer with above

Comment: let me know if its not clear

Comment: run the query and see the result what happens, I think it should work if you have the same table structure

Comment: @www.sblog.in  testing...

Comment: @www.sblog.in my above query is working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v_db` and `f_db` databases are located in same server

and it is work for me

`INSERT INTO v_db.app_user (SELECT * FROM f_db.app_user AS t WHERE t.user_id = 100003083401232)`

Comment: i have not tried ur code, but it look correct, my above code also working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
select *into destination_database.dbo.destination table from _
source_database.dbo.source table where 1 = 2
```

Comment: This won't work -- this will attempt to `create` a new table, not `insert` into an existing one...

Comment: it will copy only the similar table structure not the data

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
----Create TestTable
CREATE TABLE TestTable (FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100))
----INSERT INTO TestTable using SELECT
INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Person
WHERE EmailPromotion = 2
----Verify that Data in TestTable
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM TestTable
----Clean Up Database
DROP TABLE TestTable
GO
```

Comment: thats long, don have time to write this much of code, NOT good practice for me

Comment: ok try this then INSERT INTO Destination
            (EnrollNo,
             CheckIn,
             CheckOut,
             DiffTime)
SELECT EnrollNo,
       CheckIn,
       CheckOut,
       DiffTime
FROM   Source

Answer (score 0):

You must specify in your query `db2.table attributes` before doing

```
SELECT * FROM db1.table t  where t.restaurant_id=12
```

ie:

```
INSERT INTO db2.table (attribut1, attribut2,...)
SELECT * FROM db1.table t  where t.restaurant_id=12;
```

Comment: why do you need to write columns if you have same table structure

Comment: thats long, i am looking for query similer to mine

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[schema].[table] 
(SELECT * FROM [DB].[schema].[table] t  where t.restaurant_id=12);
```

But make sure there is not duplication on primary key column and also there is not auto increment column in table.